# Select subquery inside then of case when statement, sqlite bug?

Tags: sql, sqlite, case

I'm finding that when I try to select a column in a SQL case statement, it doesn't work unless I wrap it in a numeric function. The max(price) seems to select the value in the column, while just price, or `price` always returns blank.

I think its a bug.

This doesn't work:

```
SELECT 
auction,
CASE WHEN auction='1'
    THEN (select max(bid.amount) from bid where bid.auction_id = auction.id)
    ELSE price
END as price_string
FROM product
```

This works:

```
SELECT 
auction,
CASE WHEN auction='1'
    THEN (select max(bid.amount) from bid where bid.auction_id = auction.id)
    ELSE max(price)
END as price_string 
FROM product
```

Edit: fixed comma.

Comment: One difference I see is the extra comma you placed in the first one after `price_string`... which looks wrong to me.  But you don't specify what it means when you say, "it doesn't work," so that makes it harder to troubleshoot.

Comment: These two queries behave completely differently because of the aggregate function. Show some example data and the desired result.

Comment: Ah, when I say it doesn't work, I mean that it returns blank, not that the query fails. And also, the column price is on the table itself, which means it only has one possible value per row; it is not a set.

Comment: @thouliha What is `auction.id`?  I see it in your `WHERE` clause of the subquery, but I don't see any other reference or definition for a table named `auction` in your queries.  I think my answer may be totally wrong, but I need to know what that is referring to before I can put my finger on what is really going on here.

Comment: auction.id is an optional reference to an auction table. An item in this system always has a price, but can optionally have an auction with bids too.

Comment: But there is no other reference to this table anywhere in either query.  This should generate an error...

Answer (score 2):

This is not a bug.

In the query that doesn't work, the two halves of your `CASE` statement are incompatible.  You have an aggregate function (`MAX(bid.amount)`) that returns a single value for one part of your `CASE` statement, and the name of a column, which will return a set, for the other part of your `CASE` statement.  You cannot mix aggregates and sets like this.

The query that works does so because both halves of the `CASE` statement are returning aggregate values and are therefore compatible.

Take a simple table:

```
test_table
col1  |  col2
1        7
5        14
8        3
3        9
```

If I query like this:

```
SELECT col1 FROM test_table
```

I'll get this result, a set:

```
col1 
1        
5        
8       
3
```

But if I query like this:

```
SELECT MAX(col1) FROM test_table
```

I'll get a single value:

```
8
```

Comment: I'm still a bit confused. That column named price, is on the table itself, which means it only has one possible value per row. It is not a set.

Comment: Yes, one value per row, and it's returning that value for every row, and is therefore a set.  When you use `MAX`, it's not returning the `MAX` for every row (that wouldn't make sense), it's returning the `MAX` of *all* the rows, so it's only returning one single value.

Comment: Okay, so let me get this straight: When you select, it only selects a single value per row, but if its in a case statement, it suddenly has every table row available?

Comment: No, your subquery is what is using every row.  That has nothing to do with the case statement.  You have started a new query when you put that second SELECT in there

Comment: Your subquery is returning a single value, the maximum bid.amount in the entire bid table.  I'm afraid I'm only confusing you more...

Comment: ...and now I think I am confusing myself as well...  let me think about this a bit

Comment: No problem. What I'm trying to do is this: I have a price table, that may also be having an auction. If it is an auction, then display the highest bid. If its not an auction(IE auction=false), then just gimme that price column that's not a subquery.

Comment: Also, only one section of the case statement is using a (select ...) subquery. The other part of the case statement is just returning a column with a single value per row.